# Migration from Ibatis to MyBatis

Tags: java, xml, mybatis, ibatis

i am migrating ibatis to mybatis, and i have the following code:

```
    <dynamic prepend="AND SDLG.COD_N_TIPO_LIMITE_GEOGRAFICO IN">
        <isEqual property="incluirLimitesGeograficos" compareValue="true">
            <isNotEmpty property="listaLimitesGeograficos"> 
                    <iterate property="listaLimitesGeograficos" open="(" close=")" conjunction="," >                
                        <isNotNull property="listaLimitesGeograficos[].codTipoLimiteGeo">

                            #listaLimitesGeograficos[].codTipoLimiteGeo:DECIMAL#    

                        </isNotNull>
                    </iterate>
            </isNotEmpty>
        </isEqual>
```

I do it like this, and i want to know if its correct:

```
        AND SDLG.COD_N_TIPO_LIMITE_GEOGRAFICO IN
        <if test="incluirLimitesGeograficos">
            <!--
    Sorry, I can`t migrate  listaLimitesGeograficos
    See console output for further details 
-->
            <if test="listaLimitesGeograficos != null and listaLimitesGeograficos.size() > 0"> 
                    <foreach collection="listaLimitesGeograficos" item="item" open="(" close=")" separator="," >                
                        <if test="item.codTipoLimiteGeo != null">

                            #{item.codTipoLimiteGeo, jdbcType=DECIMAL}

                        </if>
                    </foreach>
            </if>
        </if>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, already figured it out.

passed to

If i am wrong, please correct me, because is important, thank you.